# Is bitcoin Merkle tree always binary?

Tags: binary-tree, bitcoin, merkle-tree

Is bitcoin Merkle tree always binary?

(1) I am wondering about the lookup efficiency of the Merkle tree.

(2) I haven't found any evidence that Merkle trees are mandatory binary, which would allow a O(log2 n) lookup algorithm.

(3) If a node may have an arbitrary number of children, then the lookup function would have a O(logK n * K), where K is the maximum number of allowed child nodes (as far as I remember).

Answer (score 1):

Merkle Trees by definition are binary, look at the [original patent here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4309569A/en). The tree structure in Bitcoin is binary too.

The trees aren't lookup trees like traditional search trees, rather they're used as a way to get rid of blockchain data later but have a proof that given a "root node" specific data exists in a block.

Instead of having to transmit an entire Bitcoin block with `n` transactions to show that your transaction exists in a specific block, you only have to provide `log(n)` nodes from the merkle tree.